# This fabric-like twist effect can be done only in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Hello guys i am learning illustrator, my question is this type of image
http://www.shutterstock.com/pic-129229757/stock-vector-modern-spiral-infographics-options-banner-vector-illustration-can-be-used-for-workflow-layout.html?src=rLOI0N-oEQllQwlV1mhO1A-1-0

[image]

Can it be done only in Illustrator? It doesn't looks like a typical vector, but I saw shutterstock sell it like a vector.

If no what are the tools? What workflow is used for it?

Thanks and sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 4):

9 times in 10 a vector image with realistic-looking shading made in Illustrator is made using the very powerful but rather tricky **[gradient mesh tool](http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/articles/20-tutorials-to-help-master-illustrators-gradient-mesh)**. It's not an easy tool to master and takes good judgement and patience to use well, but it's worth investing some time to learn.

The above link is a directory of 20 tutorials that should help give a head start.

[image]

As for the grainy texture, these kind of **textures can be applied directly to the vector image using effects**, which is a good approach as it maintains the vector image scalability - even if it's a raster effect, the effect will be automatically re-calculated at different sizes and resolutions. [Here's an example tutorial](http://vectips.com/tutorials/create-grainy-textures/).

[image]

---

Another alternate approach is to **set up the base image in Illustrator then move to Photoshop to apply texture**. This approach feels more free and natural, but isn't so good for long term scalability since you're creating a fixed resolution raster image. If you're working to a specified size, it's a good approach.

The designer [James White](http://blog.signalnoise.com/) uses this approach really well, and made this animated gif ([with writeup](http://blog.signalnoise.com/2013/04/02/green-lantern-illustration-animated-gif/)) which illustrates it. The first step is the shapes in Illustrator with a a few brushes for basic texture, then the lighting and detail is painted on in Photoshop:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Even if this image doesn't look like a 'flat' vector image, probably it was drawn using a vector editor with some effects (opacity, blur, shadows) and applying some textures or filters (see [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/illustrator/cs/using/WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-61e5a.html#WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-61e4a) for Adobe Illustrator)

You can use Adobe Illustrator or [CorelDRAW](http://www.corel.com) or [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org) (which is free) as well, but you need some basic graphic skills.

I suggest you to start from some tutorials ([this](http://www.noupe.com/tutorial/adobe-illustrator-tutorial-create-set-sleek-web-ribbons.html) is similar, or see [here](http://inkscapetutorials.wordpress.com/category/3d-effects/) or [here](http://veerle-v2.duoh.com/blog/comments/creating_a_ribbon_in_adobe_illustrator/) - see [here](http://vector.tutsplus.com/tutorials/designing/create-a-vintage-art-deco-poster-with-illustrators-grain-effect/) for the grainy effect) to create your base image or use an existing files (e.g. [this](http://openclipart.org/detail/94681/red-ribbon-collection-by-rferran) or [this](http://vector4free.com/vectors/search/ribbon/)) and then proceed by testing and adjusting your drawing by hand until you are satisfied.

Comment: For me looks like photoshop hand or maybe 3d, how do u make the grany matte texture only in illustrator? Thanks for share his opinions

Comment: It's surely a vector image with some effects. In Illustrator.... `Effect-> Texture-> Grain`. In Inkscape you can use the filters.